# Existe SmtpClient.Timeout com valor infinito?

Tags: c#, .net, smtp

Existe alguma forma de colocar `SmtpClient.Timeout` com o valor infinito? Caso sim, como?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por "sorte" não pode. Não faz sentido fazer isso, mas se quiser fazer errado pode usar o tempo [`int.MaxValue`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.maxvalue?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0), vai dar quase um mês.

Se precisa disto pode estar com outro problema. Se **um** envio de e-mail demorar mais que 5 segundos, é pouco provável que ele ocorrerá.

Essa técnica é inadequada. Se não conseguir depois de um curto período de tempo deve tentar novamente em outra tentativa, tomar providência porque falhar, pelo menos *logando* o ocorrido.

Outra técnica é enviar assincronamente, assim não trava o computador nessa tarefa e pode ir para os demais. Qualquer envio de e-mail deveria ser feito assim. Se a API do [`SmtpClient`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) fosse feita hoje já teria incentivado isso (de fato ela foi modificada para aceitar esta forma).